# MTProto msg_id replay-attacks

Tags: bit-manipulation, telegram, mtproto

The [MTProto documentation](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/description#message-identifier-msg-id) says, referring to the unique `msg_id`:

> to counter replay-attacks the lower 32 bits of msg_id passed by the client must not be empty and must present a fractional part of the time point when the message was created

When it comes to bit operations I feel like I'm dumb, so what would be the "way" to ensure the lower 32 bits are never empty?

Also, I don't completely understand

> a fractional part of the time ...

Answer (score 0):

What it is trying to say here is that unix time is standardised to go down to the second, a fractional part of the time here is a fraction of a second. You ensure the lower 32-bits are never empty by using a time source more accurate than standard Unix time (preferably nanoseconds but milliseconds work too) that can provide accurate data for the lower 32-bits.